# How to use MongoDb aggregation framework to calculate daily records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a Log collection that is meant to give stats on daily records

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ee4f58be451502a40fb2a83",
        "name": "Cement",
        "description": "Construction",
        "price": 1400,
        "quantity": 30,
        "quantitySold": -5,
        "itemDestination": "Trocadero",
        "createdAt": "2020-06-13T15:49:32.684Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-13T15:49:32.684Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eddea221bab5221e4ee2238",
        "name": "Pop",
        "description": "Construction",
        "price": 500,
        "quantity": 19,
        "quantitySold": -5,
        "itemDestination": "Amore",
        "createdAt": "2020-06-08T07:34:58.569Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-08T07:34:58.569Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5edde9f51bab5221e4ee2237",
        "name": "Pop",
        "description": "Construction",
        "price": 500,
        "quantity": 24,
        "quantitySold": -6,
        "itemDestination": "Trocadero",
        "createdAt": "2020-06-08T07:34:13.700Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-06-08T07:34:13.700Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I would like to get daily records of totalQuantitySold and daily average of quantitySold. But was only able to do the following

```
//logcontroller.js


    Log.aggregate([

        {
            $group:
              {
                _id: "$name",
                totalAmountSold:{$sum:"$quantitySold" },
                avgQuantitySold: { $avg: "$quantitySold" },


              }
          },
    ])
```

output :

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": "Cement",
            "totalQuantitySold": -5,
            "avgQuantitySold": -5
        },
        {
            "_id": "Pop",
            "totalQuantitySold": -11,
            "avgQuantitySold": -5.5
        }
    ]
}
```

However, i have the challenge of extracting these stats based on daily entries... would appreciate if anyone can help out. here is my log schema:

```
    {
        // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
        quantitySold: { type: Number, required: true },
        supplier: String,
        taxable: Boolean,
        itemDest: String,

    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

// Create model from the schema
const Log = mongoose.model('Log', LogSchema);

// Export model
module.exports = Log;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include date in your grouping key. Since you have `ISODate` stored as `createdAt`/`updatedAt` you can use [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to convert date + into into `Y-m-d` format:

```
Log.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { name: "$name", day: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$updatedAt" } } },
            totalAmountSold:{$sum:"$quantitySold" },
            avgQuantitySold: { $avg: "$quantitySold" }
        }
    },
])
```

You can also remove the `name` part from `_id` if you need to filter by date only.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I3gFmkpJD2U)